# How to disable Directional focus navigation inCSS

Tags: html, css

In this example below, I would like to disable

Directional focus navigation: the ‘nav-up’, ‘nav-right’, ‘nav-down’, ‘nav-left’ properties

for any elements in an HTML page.

```
button { position:absolute }

button#b1 {
    top:0; left:50%;
    nav-index:1;
    nav-right:#b2; nav-left:#b4;
    nav-down:#b2; nav-up:#b4;
}

button#b2 {
    top:50%; left:100%;
    nav-index:2;
    nav-right:#b3; nav-left:#b1;
    nav-down:#b3; nav-up:#b1;
}

button#b3 {
    top:100%; left:50%;
    nav-index:3;
    nav-right:#b4; nav-left:#b2;
    nav-down:#b4; nav-up:#b2;
}

button#b4 {
    top:50%; left:0;
    nav-index:4;
    nav-right:#b1; nav-left:#b3;
    nav-down:#b1; nav-up:#b3;
}
```

example from 
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#nav-dir

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
* {
   nav-right: #non-existing-id; 
   nav-left: #non-existing-id;
   nav-down: #non-existing-id;
   nav-up: #non-existing-id;
}
```

asterisk targets every css object, and targeting a non existing id would make your nav key not to move anywhere.